# Text-Shadow CSS not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, css

I have applied the Text-Shadow on asp.net Grid, its working fine in Firefox and Chrome but it is not rendering in IE11.

When I tried frequent refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) i.e. 5-6 times then it worked. SO please let me know how can I fix it ?

```
.grid_row
{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE11 has this feature (F12). If the text-shadow was overriden you'd see it immediately as a crossed-over property, if you have use 'X-UA-Compatible' tag in 'meta' section then please remove it.

```
I think JSFiddle will help you more http://jsfiddle.net/G8wgb/3/
```